# Dynamic Marketing List in MS Dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a dynamic marketing list in Microsoft Dynamics which I am trying to query via the web service. However the dynamic list always returns 0 results via the web service. Static lists work fine via the web service.

Why does the web service not return results for the dynamic marketing list?

Answer (score 0):

Because dynamic lists contain query based on which members are being retrieved. In case you want to retrieve members of dynamic list you will have to retrieve query and anfter that - members of list.